# Red instagram notification bubble - css

Tags: css

I really want to create the red instagram bubble in css *with* the rounded tip as pictured here:

[image]

I have pretty much everything except for the rounded tip, and I'm unsure how I should do it best...

This is what I have so far:

```css
.notif {
  display: block;
  height: 35px;
  background: #E95950;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 5px rgba(233, 89, 80, 0.6));
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 5px rgba(233, 89, 80, 0.6));
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 30px;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

.notif:after {
    content: '';
    border-left: 8px solid transparent;
    border-right: 8px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 8px solid #E95950;
    position: absolute;
    left: 25%;
    top: -7px;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-65%);
    transform: translateX(-65%);
}

.notifItem {
  display:inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 8px 5px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}


.notifItem:first-child {
  margin-left: 8px;
}

.notifItem:last-child {
  margin-right: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="notif">
    <div class="notifItem">33</div>
    <div class="notifItem">2</div>
    <div class="notifItem">5</div>
  </div>
```

So this looks good, I have the tip where I personally want it, I'm just not sure how I can mimic that rounded tip...

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be a simple rectangular box, with rounded corners and `skew` or `rotated`.

This element can be used as pseudo element and placed behind the box which you already done.

https://codepen.io/AugustinF/pen/odmvLV

```css
.notif {
  display: block;
  height: 35px;
  background: #E95950;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 5px rgba(233, 89, 80, 0.6));
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 5px rgba(233, 89, 80, 0.6));
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 30px;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

.notif:after {
  content: '';
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #E95950;
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
  left: 25px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  transform: skew(-30deg, 45deg);
  z-index: -1;
}

.notifItem {
  display:inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 8px 5px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}


.notifItem:first-child {
  margin-left: 8px;
}

.notifItem:last-child {
  margin-right: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="notif">
    <div class="notifItem">33</div>
    <div class="notifItem">2</div>
    <div class="notifItem">5</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: @JaneDoe I'm glad if I could help, thanks for voting and selecting.